# Accessing django website hosted on vm with mobile device

Tags: django, vagrant

I run my django website with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` on Vagrant which is set up to forward `8080` port to `8081` on host machine. I'm able to access this website on host by going to it's local ip (`192.168.X.X`) but can't on mobile device (of course also by going into it's local ip).

Any idea? All I could find about this is to run server with `0.0.0.0` what is already happening in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I've forgot to enable `public_network` in my Vagrantfile.